# SQLAlchemy an error when swamping the name of the database table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to show the database data when clicked on any dropdown link.

[image]

The HTML code:

```
 <input type='text' placeholder='Search...' id='products' onkeyup='filterFunction()'>
      {% product in all_products %}
        <a href='{{ url_for('home', product=product.name) }}'>{{ product.name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
```

The request.args.get is send.

[image: product]

Then in main.py the request.args.get is replacing the name of the table:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
all_products = db.session.query(Product).all()     
current_product = request.args.get('product')

display_product = db.session.query(Product, current_product).join(current_product).all()

return render_template('index.html', all_products=all_products)
```

My database:

```
class Products(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(50))

class Product1(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
  size= db.Column(db.String(50))
  dim_a = db.Column(db.Integer)
  dim_b = db.Column(db.Integer)
  dim_c = db.Column(db.Integer)
   
class Product2(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
  size = db.Column(db.String(50))
  dim_a = db.Column(db.Integer)
  dim_b = db.Column(db.Integer)
  dim_c = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error

> 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual column expression 'product1' should be explicitly declared with text('product1'), or
> use literal_column('product1') for more specificity'

when using current_product as table name.